# Getting errors after hitting ld command for swig on Windows

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, swig

I want to use swig on Windows. I did the setup and could generate .o files, but am unable to generate .so files.

I took a copy of example.c and example.i from the Examples folder in swig, and then ran the below commands:

```
swig -python example.i
gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include
ld -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

After hitting the ld command it is throwing a lot of errors:

> ld: example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'

> ld: example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `strlen'

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Don't use `ld` directly, use the GCC front-end program `gcc` to link as well. It will add the libraries needed, like the standard C library (which contains the missing `strlen` function). For the Python functions you need to link with the Python libraries yourself though,

Comment: I have used gcc as well but still getting errors:  D:\Swig>gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'

Comment: Like I said, you still need to link with the Python libraries. There must be plenty of tutorials online about using SWIG and how to build and what libraries to link. What tutorial are you following? What does it say about building?

Comment: ohk, thanks, will check, i am following swig documentation

Comment: This issue is resolved, i used setup.py which could create .pyd , and i could import the C Module in Python.

Comment: @sanujap You should post your resolution as an answer and click the checkmark next to it to indicate to future readers what the solution was. Don't answer in comments.